# Making an attribute required only if another attribute is set

Tags: xsd

Is it possible to make an attribute `required` iff another attribute is set?

E.g. In the following code, `viewId` attribute has to be made `required`, iff `action` attribute is set.

XML:

```
<node id="id1" destination="http://www.yahoo.com" />
<node id="id2" action="demo" viewId="demo.asp"/>
```

If this is possible, could you please show me how this is done. As of now, I have `viewId` set `required` in all the cases, because of which the 1st `node` element fails validation.

```
<xsd:attribute name="focusViewId" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible with XSD 1.0 alone. You have to employ the use of another XML schema language, in addition to or instead of XSD,  or move to XSD 1.1.

Another alternative may be to restructure your schema. If @destination is mutually exclusive with { @action, @viewId} maybe you could use elements instead which would then allow you to employ `xsd:choice`.

UPDATE: for an XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="node">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="destination" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="action" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="viewId" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:assert test="(@viewId) or not(@action)" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: How would the original question be solved in XSD 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an abstract complex type for your element "node" (let's call it abstactNode) which contains the definition of @id.

Then create a complex type "nodeWithDestination" that extends abstactNode, with the definition of the @destination.

An a second complex type "nodeWithActionAndViewId" that extends abstactNode as well, with @action and @viewId attribute definitions.

Your XML would look like this:

```
<node id="id1" destination="http://www.yahoo.com" xsi:type="nodeWithDestination"/>
<node id="id2" action="demo" viewId="demo.asp" xsi:type="nodeWithActionAndViewId"/>
```

Would that match your need ?

Comment: After Petru's answer I did some research and figured out this is a possible workaround, but not something we really want to do. XML file generally comes from users of our framework and hence we have very little control in forcing our users to define `xsi:type`.