# How to specify in a XML schema that 2 attributes can't be present at the same time?

Tags: xml, xsd

Anyone knows how to prevent a XML to have 2 attributes at the same time?

I have an XML which gives information about liquid containers :

**What I want**

Example 1 :

```
<container>
  <bottle volume=1/>
</container>
```

Example 2 :

```
<container>
  <bottle size="small"/>
</container>
```

Example 3 :

```
<container>
  <bottle/>
</container>
```

I use 2 different attributes to indicate the quantity of liquid a container can contain but I don't want to have the possibility to indicate twice the same information by putting both attributes at the same time :

**What I don't want**

```
<container>
  <bottle volume=1 size="small"/>
</container>
```

Anyone knows how to forbid that?

EDIT : I must use XSD 1.0

Comment: XSD. 1.0 or XSD 1.1?

Comment: Similar sort of question, but in this case making something mandatory.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746049/making-an-attribute-required-only-if-another-attribute-is-set

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done in XSD 1.0.

It's easily done in XSD 1.1 using assertions (or type alternatives).

The traditional way to do this without XSD 1.1 is to use Schematron for a second validation pass.